# Wagtail: accessing data models outside of an app

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Very simple really. But I'm new to django and by extension wagtail.
I want to display the posts from an app on the homepage, or within any other django app for that matter.

Current app structure:

```
website/home/
website/blog/
website/portfolio/
```

Currently I can easily display the posts from 'portfolio items' in a nice for loop on the 'portfolio index page'.

When I try to extend this to the homepage, nothing works.

How do I access the models, etc of one app from another (in this case, rendering data from 'portfolio items' on 'home'.

Portfolio modelss.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django import forms, utils

from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
from wagtail.wagtailcore.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.wagtailsnippets.models import register_snippet
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, InlinePanel, MultiFieldPanel, PageChooserPanel
from wagtail.wagtailimages.models import Image
from wagtail.wagtailimages.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel

from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey, ParentalManyToManyField
from modelcluster.tags import ClusterTaggableManager
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase, Tag as TaggitTag



class PortfolioHome(Page):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('description', classname="full"),
    ]


class PortfolioPage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    feature_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )
    categories = ParentalManyToManyField('portfolio.PortfolioPageCategory', blank=True)
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through='portfolio.PortfolioPageTag', blank=True)
    pub_date = utils.timezone.now()
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        FieldPanel('categories', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),
        FieldPanel('tags'),
        ImageChooserPanel('feature_image'),
    ]

class PortfolioPageTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey('PortfolioPage', related_name='portfolio_tags')

@register_snippet
class Tag(TaggitTag):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = "Tag portfolio"
        verbose_name_plural = "Tags portfolio"


@register_snippet
class PortfolioPageCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=80)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        FieldPanel('slug'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category portfolio"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories portfolio"
```

Homepage models.py:

```
    from __future__ import unicode_literals

    from django.db import models
    from django import forms

    from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
    from wagtail.wagtailcore.fields import RichTextField
    from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, InlinePanel, MultiFieldPanel, PageChooserPanel

    from portfolio.models import PortfolioPage


    class HomePage(Page):
        body = RichTextField(blank=True)
        content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
            FieldPanel('body', classname="homepage"),
        ]
```

Home_page.html template:

```
{% extends "home/base.html" %}

{% load static wagtailcore_tags wagtailroutablepage_tags wagtailimages_tags %}

{% block body_class %}template-homepage{% endblock %}

{% block home_content %}
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <div class="content">

    {% for page in page.get_children.specific %}

        <h2>{{ page.get_children.title }}</h2>
        <h2><a href="{% pageurl page %}">{{ page.title }}</a></h2>


        {% if page.feature_image %}
        <section>
            <span class="image featured">
                {% image page.feature_image fill-800x450 as feature_image %}
                <img alt="{{ page.feature_image.title }}" src="{{ feature_image.url }}">
            </span>
        </section>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}


    </div>
    <p><a href="{% url 'wagtailadmin_home' %}">Wagtail admin</a></p>
{% endblock home_content %}
```

portfolio_home.html template (this renders all data perfectly):
To clarify, I want this behaviour on the homepage...

```
{% extends "portfolio/base.html" %}

{% load static i18n wagtailcore_tags wagtailroutablepage_tags wagtailuserbar wagtailimages_tags %}

{% block body_class %}portfolio-item{% endblock %}


{% block portfolio_content %}

    {{ page.title }}
    <br>
    {{ page.description }}
    <br>
    {{ page.body|richtext }}
    <br>
    {# {% image page.feature_image original class="feature_image" %} #}

    {% for portfolio in latest_portfolio_list %}
        <li><a href="/first_app/{{ portfolio.id }}/">{{ portfolio.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}

    <p><a href="{{ page.get_parent.url }}">Return to portfolio</a></p>

{% endblock portfolio_content %}
```

If you can help I'll be very grateful. Also if you can suggest some resources to better understand these concepts, please do. I've worked my way through a couple of tutorials to get to this stage, but I'm now stuck!

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the `context` dictionary of `HomePage` Page to pass `latest_portfolio_list` to its template.

```
class HomePage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="homepage"),
    ]

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super(HomePage, self).get_context(request)
        context['latest_portfolio_list'] = PortfolioPage.objects.live()
        return context
```

Then loop over `lastest_portfolio_list` in your homepage template.

#### Reference:

- http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.11.1/topics/pages.html#customising-template-context

Comment: That's awesome! You've levelled me up, thank you so much. I'll do a lot more reading about this concept for sure...

Now I have this working, I wonder if you could help me a tiny bit more?
I would like to show a single item, not the whole list. I've tried to filter to just 'last` but I get an `'PortfolioPage' object is not iterable` error. Any ideas?

Comment: If passing a single item, you don't need the loop in the template. You can pass this as `last_portfolio` in your template context and access it directly`<li><a href="/first_app/{{ last_portfolio.id }}/">{{ last_portfolio.title }}</a></li>`

Comment: Thank you again. Took a few mins to work it out, but it's sorted! You're awesome!